# Out-of-process COM server migrated to in-process COM server causes callbacks to block

Tags: c++, com

We have an existing network messaging server that implements a custom communications protocol that we are migrating to an in-process COM object.  The server is implemented as a free threaded out-of-process COM server.  The clients can register with the server (think publish-subscribe) to receive messages.

After migration we noticed several dead locks when calling GUI related functions, e.g. SetWindowPos, RedrawWindow, EnumWindows, etc.  After doing some research I found that this was due to callbacks happening on a thread other than the main GUI thread (message pump).  The callbacks are custom COM callbacks that derive from IUnknown, so we are not using connection points.

What's interesting is if a create a simple MFC dialog project, everything works.  But in our main application it fails.  Our main application (20+ years old and doing things now it was never designed for) is an MFC dialog project.  In response to a message, the MFC dialog project loads a DLL that, in turn, creates an MFC dialog and registers with the COM server for messages.  When the DLL dialog receives a message it calls one of the three example GUI related functions above, and blocks.

This use to work for an out-of-process COM server, so I know there is a way to get the callback to be within the context of the clients main GUI thread but have been unable find the 'magic' code to make it work.  I did stumble upon SendMessageCallback but can't get the asynchronous callback function to be called.

The COM callbacks into the client are handled via a thread inside the in-process COM server.  The thread is initialized with CoInitialize, which from my research means STA.  I've tried changing this to CoInitializeEx and tested with MTA.  I've also tried changing the COM server threading model to STA, MTA, Both, and Free.  As you can see, I'm really starting to throw darts. here.

Any help would be appreciated.

I did order the Don Box books, Essential COM and Effective COM, but they will not arrive until later this week.

**EDIT:**

Our main application:
Inside of CApp derived class' InitInstance

1. AfxOleInit()

Inside of CDialog derived class' OnInitDialog

1. CoCreateInstance (Messaging COM Object)
2. Allocate callback pointer.  The client callback is an interface that derives from IUnknown.  Then a callback class derives from the client callback and implements the AddRef/Release interfaces.  When the client creates the callback the client passes a pointer to itself so the callback can call the client.
3. MessageComObject->Register(callback pointer)

Inside MessageCOMObject:

1. MessageComObject adds the callback to the GIT and saves the cookie.
2. MessageComObject starts a thread to 'send' callbacks to the client.

Some point in time later the main application receives a 'message' via the callback pointer.  The callback is initiated from within the MessageComObject.
Inside the MessageCOMObject:

1. MessageComObject gets the callback from the GIT using the cookie
2. MessageComObject calls a function on the callback interface

Inside the callback interface's derived class:

1. Calls the client callback function

Inside the CDialog derived class' callback handler:

1. Calls LoadLibrary on a DLL (what gets loaded is data driven)
2. Calls exported function from DLL.

Inside DLL's exported function:

1. Create CWnd object
2. CoCreateInstance (Messaging COM Object)
3. Allocate callback pointer (same as above)
4. MessageCOMObject->Register

Inside MessageCOMObject:

1. MessageComObject adds the callback to the GIT and saves the cookie.
2. MessageComObject starts a thread to 'send' callbacks to the client.

Some point in time later the DLL receives a message:

1. MessageComObject gets the callback from the GIT using the cookie, GIT returns 'Catastrophic Failure'

Code

Declaring the callback in the IDL file:

```
[
    object,
    uuid(...),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMessageRouterCallback : IUnknown
{
   ...
};

[
    object,
    uuid(...),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMessageRouter : IUnknown
{
    ...
};

[
    uuid(....),
    version(1.0),
]
library MessageRouterCOMLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(....)  
    ]
    coclass MessageRouter
    {
            [default] interface IMessageRouter;
    };
};
```

The in-process COM DLL

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMessageRouter :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComMultiThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CMessageRouter, &CLSID_MessageRouter>,
    public IMessageRouter
{
public:

DECLARE_GET_CONTROLLING_UNKNOWN()

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CMessageRouter)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IMessageRouter)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_AGGREGATE(IID_IMarshal, m_pUnkMarshaler.p)
END_COM_MAP()

    CComPtr<IUnknown> m_pUnkMarshaler;

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    DWORD callbackRegistrationId;

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        //- TODO: Add error checking
        IUnknown *unknown;
        DllGetClassObject(IID_IMessageRouterCallback, IID_IUnknown, (void**)&unknown);
        CoRegisterClassObject(IID_IMessageRouterCallback, unknown, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &callbackRegistrationId);
        CoRegisterPSClsid(IID_IMessageRouterCallback, IID_IMessageRouterCallback);

        return CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler(GetControllingUnknown(), 
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
        if (callbackRegistrationId)
            CoRevokeClassObject(callbackRegistrationId);
        callbackRegistrationId = 0;

        if (m_pUnkMarshaler)
            m_pUnkMarshaler.Release();
    }
}
```

Where callback is registered:

```
boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(callbacksMutex);

//- callback is the raw interface pointer from the client
//- The class Callback contains a pointer to the raw client callback
//- and the global process ID.  The raw pointer is AddRef/Release in
//- the Callback class' constructor and destructor.
ptr = Callback::Pointer(new Callback(callback));
DWORD callbackId = 0;

HRESULT result = globalInterfaceTable->RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(callback, IID_IMessageRouterCallback, &callbackId);
if (SUCCEEDED(result))
{
    ptr->globalCallbackId = callbackId;
    callbackMap[callback] = ptr;
    //- NOTE: uses raw pointer as key into map.  This key is only
    //-       ever used during un-register.
    //- callbackMap is a std::map of Callback instances indexed by the raw pointer.
}
```

Callback thread:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

while (processCallbackThreadRunning)
{
    QueueMessage message = messageQueue.Pop();
    if (!processCallbackThreadRunning)
        break;

    //- Make a copy because callbacks may be added/removed during
    //- this call.
    CallbackMap callbacks;
    {
        boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> guard(callbacksMutex);
        callbacks = callbackMap;
    }

    for (CallbackMap::iterator callback = callbacks.begin(); callback != callbacks.end(); ++callback)
    {
        try
        {
            IMessageRouterCallback *mrCallback = NULL;
            HRESULT result = globalInterfaceTable->GetInterfaceFromGlobal(callback->second->globalCallbackId,IID_IMessageRouterCallback,(void **) &mrCallback);
            if (SUCCEEDED(result))
            {
                result = mrCallback->MessageHandler((unsigned char*)message.messageBuffer->Data(), message.messageBuffer->Length(), message.metaData.id, message.metaData.fromId, CComBSTR(message.metaData.fromAddress.c_str()));
                if (FAILED(result))
                {
                    ... log debug
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ... log debug
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            ... log debug
        }
    }

    MessagePool::Push(message.messageBuffer);
}

CoUninitialize();
```

Client's implementation of the callback:

```
template <class CALLBACKCLASS>
class CMessageRouterCallback :
    public CComBase<IMessageRouterCallback>
{
    CMessageRouterCallback( CALLBACKCLASS *pCallbackClass = NULL) :
        m_pCallbackClass(pCallbackClass)
    {
        AddRef();   //- Require by CComBase.  This makes it so that this
                    //- class does not get automatically deleted when
                    //- Message Router is done with the class.
    }

    STDMETHODIMP MessageHandler( UCHAR *szBuffer, int nSize, DWORD dwTransCode, DWORD dwSenderID, BSTR bstrFromIP )
    {
        if ( m_pCallbackClass != NULL )
        {
            m_pCallbackClass->MessageHandler( szBuffer, nSize, dwTransCode, dwSenderID, bstrFromIP );
        }

        return S_OK;
    }
}
```

CComBase implements the IUnknown interface:

```
template < class BASE_INTERFACE, const IID* piid = &__uuidof(BASE_INTERFACE) >
class CComBase :
    public BASE_INTERFACE
{
protected:
    ULONG   m_nRefCount;

public:

    CComBase() : m_nRefCount(0) {}

    STDMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
    {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == *piid )
            *ppv=this;
        else
            return *ppv=0,E_NOINTERFACE;
        AddRef();

        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
    {
        return ++m_nRefCount;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
    {
        if (!--m_nRefCount)
        {
            delete this;
            return 0;
        }
        return m_nRefCount;
    }

    virtual ~CComBase() {}

};
```

The client then uses it:

```
class Client
{
    CMessageRouterCallback<Client> *callback;

    Client(IMessageRouter *messageRouter)
    {
        callback = new CMessageRouterCallback<this>();

        messageRouter->Register(..., callback);
    }

    void MessageHandler(...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: You don't have that fairy around anymore to marshal calls, it is now up to you to make the callbacks in a thread-safe way.  Marshaling the interface pointer in your worker thread is a hard requirement to ensure that the callback runs on the UI thread and can safely make user32 calls.  CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream() is the low-level function,  IGlobalInterfaceTable makes it easy to use, PostMessage() is the generic way to get code to run on the UI thread.

Comment: @Hans  Thanks Hans.  I'm familiar with IGlobalInterfaceTable and PostMessage.  I'll take a look at CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream.  I've tried looking, but again come up empty.  Is there an existing Windows message that I can pass to PostMessage to handle part of this, or do I need to roll my own?

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me why you are not using IGlobalInterfaceTable.  Having the COM infrastructure taking care of it (it uses PostMessage and CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream under the hood) is the simplest approach.

Comment: Originally, I had been using IGlobalInterfaceTable.  But it was returning an HRESULT (I can't remember the exact wording) indicating that it was not required.  I can easily add it back in now that we are further along in our integration and see what happens...

Comment: @Hans I added the usage of IGlobalInterfaceTable back into the code and fortunately I am getting the same issue.  To make sure that I am using it correctly, a register the interface with the GIT where the client passes the interface into the server.  Then on the server, from within the callback thread, I query the GIT for the callback interface using the same cookie obtained during registration.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a hack, but you could have your callbacks check if they are on the UI thread; and synch to it or post a message to it if they aren't.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, that's exactly what a call to a proxy to an STA interface pointer would do.  The problem here seems to be that the interface pointer to the callback object is not being marshaled.  For instance, if the MTA (`ThreadingModel="Free"`) server objects were instantiated/activated in an STA through COM (`CoCreateInstance`, `CoGetClassObject`), a proxy to an MTA interface pointer would be returned.  The method invocation that registers the callback would actually marshal it, so the server object would obtain and store a proxy to an STA interface pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something wrong with how those callbacks are being registered.  Possible causes may be:

- A direct pointer to the callback manager's interface in the GUI thread, so you're providing direct pointers to STA objects to the callback manager too.

  Your `Callback` instance in the code you added seems to be doing exactly this, it can't blindly call the raw pointer's `Release` when destroyed.
- Your server objects are marshaled with `CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler` (not much different).

  With the FTM, you **must never** use raw pointers, and you **must always** marshal interface pointers you intend to keep and unmarshal interface pointers you previously kept, preferrably using the GIT.  And I mean **always**, if you intend to keep things safe.

I recommend you keep your server objects in MTA (`ThreadingModel="Free"`) or NA (`ThreadingModel="Neutral"`), make sure you're accessing them somehow in the GUI thread through `CoCreateInstance[Ex]` or `CoGetClassObject` and `IClassFactory::CreateInstance` (or any other object activation API), and let the "magic" happen.  This is as transparent as it can get without using the GIT or manually marshaling things between threads.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  As part of the migration our server objects are indeed marshaled with CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler.  My assumption then is that the free threaded marshaler needs to be removed?  I'll also see what I can do to get the CoCreateInstance (via CComPTR) to be within the context of the GUI thread.

Comment: The FTM is useful when an object may be accessed from any apartment, breaking a ground rule in exchange for performance (avoiding thread context switches).  However, once an FTM'ed object has references to other apartment-bound objects, you'll have to take care and marshal incoming and outgoing interface pointers, either explicitly (`CoMarshalInterface`) or preferably through the GIT.  FTM'ed objects can make this transparent to the clients.

Comment: So, you'll have to analyze and see what's good for you.  Start with safety, having MTA objects provides this to you.  If you want or need more performance, find the bottlenecks in terms of calls to your server objects and making only the relevant objects be FTM'ed, remembering to marshal incoming and outgoing interface pointers as needed.  However, if your GUI callback runs quite often, what you gain by aggregating the FTM on the object that runs it is lost in marshaling and probable context switches.

Comment: Say, have you looked at `ThreadingModel="Neutral"` yet?  It might be the easiest approach.

Comment: No I haven't.  I will give that a try.  As an aside, I am using the GIT to marshal the outgoing interfaces.  The return code is "Catastrophic Failure" (via _com_error).  Could this be a clue?  I've checked for invalid pointers/data and can't find any.  Again, thanks for your continued help.

Comment: To be more clear.  The "Catastrophic Failure" error is returned when querying the GIT for the interface.

Comment: That seems like either some proxy/stub needing registration or you need to make sure the cookie is being written (e.g. using the `volatile` keyword and `InterlockedExchangePointer`) before the 'send' thread runs.

Comment: Thanks Paulo.  I am able to verify that the cookie is getting written.  As far as proxy/stub, the VS2010 project is set to generate stubless proxies.  Also unlike our out-of-process COM server, there is not a seperate marshaling DLL that must be registered.  Am I interpreting your 'proxy/stub needing registration' correctly?

Comment: I don't know if this helps or not but I used the IComThreadingInfo interface and found that when registering a callback the apartment type is APTTYPE_MAINSTA and when invoking a callback the apartment type is APTTYPE_STA.  This is with 'ThreadingModel="Neutral"'.

Comment: Yes, you still need a proxy/stub for in-process marshaling, so you still need to register them, at the very least the callback's interface.  You can get away without the registry with either registration-free COM (manifest) or `CoRegisterPSClsid`.  What's most interesting is that I expected the new thread to be initialized for MTA, but I guess it's almost irrelevant for TNA objects.

Comment: Since the custom callback is implemented by the client, I assume I can still register the interface inside the server?  Would this be done inside FinalConstruct?  Or is there a more appropriate location?

Comment: I tried CoRegisterPSClsid in both the client and in the server.  Unfortunately I still get the catastrophic failure.  I've edited my question to include the pertinent code that deals with the callback.  I removed the extraneous code, e.g. '...'.  I know that I can initialize the thread with CoInitializeEx to get it into an MTA.  I'll also try going down that route again.

Comment: Success!! Required two things.  (1) I created a marshal DLL using the MIDL generated *_p.c file.  (2) When switching to MTA, we had errors in another out-of-process COM object.  We wrote this off as MTA must not be the correct answer.  However, after switch back to MTA I decided to find out why the other out-of-process COM server was failing.  The other COM server is our logger and the CServiceModele::Run function called CoInitialize.  I set both the logger and this project to COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED.  Everything worked.  Does this make sense or will we run into errors further down the road?

Comment: Thank you for your continued direction.  I never would have found the issue without your help.

Comment: If the objects live in the same STA and if that's the reason you don't get errors, then either you were still passing native unmarshaled pointers between apartments (most likely) or the P/S DLL was never properly registered (I doubt).  It was unfortunate of me to mention `CoRegisterPSClsid`, it's mostly a hack for EXE servers and surrogates.  The source of your problems, from what I can read from your code's comments, is that `Callback` invokes the raw interface pointer's `Release` when destroyed, which is definitely not right.  Don't even use it as a key, remove the temptation completely.

Comment: Trying removing the MACRO #define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED if it isn't already.