# How do I handle COM callbacks between two different apartments in Delphi

Tags: delphi, com

I have an in-process COM server that is free threading; call it #1. I need to call methods on this from an out-of-process COM server #2 (running STA apartment). I figured the best way was to launch #2 from #1 and use COM callbacks so that a call to #2 from #3 is passed onto #1.

I've done the equivalent of this with out-of-process programs. Program 1 launches program 2 by COM and sets up a COM callback. Program 3 connects to program 2 by COM and calls a method that makes a call to #1.

But the COM callback doesn't work with the in-process COM server and I suspect I've to implement some marshalling but am finding it very challenging. I've been reading Don Box's COM book as well as techvanguards website.

The background to this is Microsoft Dynamic Virtual Channels. The in-process COM server is the client dll end that runs in-process under MSTSC. Am I missing some obvious way to make calls to this from an out-of-process application or is my idea of launching an out-of-process COM server the right way?

I suspect I'm looking for the Delphi equivalent to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741015/out-of-process-com-server-migrated-to-in-process-com-server-causes-callbacks-to) and answer.

Comment: What's #3? It's not clear what are clients and what are servers in the picture. What do you mean exactly by "callbacks"? Are you still using COM with these?. Are they designed as COM interfaces (like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-advise) or do you mean connection points? If everything is setup correctly, there's no need for special marshaling

Comment: The programs are 1. Client dll. It's COM server (free threaded) and running in-process, invoked by mstsc.exe when you open an RDP session. It starts program 2, a COM server that is out-of-process. Program 2 uses connection points mad program 1 adds itself after connecting to 2 via early binding.

Answer (score 1):

COM should do the marshalling for you if you pass the interface pointers through interface methods. Hence, if you have control over all the interfaces involved the solution can be as easy as adding a method `SetCallback(IWhatever *callback)`, leaving all the hard work to COM.

The GIT (Global Interface Table) is not really helpful here because it works only in-process; the machine-wide equivalent would be the ROT (Running Object Table). However, farting around with GIT or ROT is not necessary here because you already have live COM connections over which you can pass the pointers.